# Heat equation solution of type $v(\frac{x^{2}}{t})$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have stucked in heat Equation $u_{t}=u_{xx}$

I look for a solution of type $v(\frac{x^{2}}{t})$.

I set $z=\frac{x^{2}}{t}$ and i end up in the ode:
$\frac{16}{t}v''(z)+(\frac{8}{x^{2}}+\frac{4t}{x^{3}}-1)v'(z)=0$

Because,

$v_{t}(x,t)=v'(z)\frac{x^{4}}{t^{4}}$

$u_{xx}(x,t)=v''(z)\frac{16x^{4}}{t^{4}}+v'(z)\frac{8x^{2}}{t^{2}}+v'(z)\frac{4x}{t^{2}}$

According to Lawrence C Evans in Partial Differential Equation in page 87,we should end up in the ode:
$4zv''(z)+(2+z)v'(z)=0$

Who i am wrong?

Comment: With $z = x^{2}/t$ \begin{align} u_{t} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \frac{x^{2}}{t} \right) \cdot v'(z) \\ &= -\frac{x^{2}}{t^{2}} v'(z) \\ u_{x} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{x^{2}}{t} \right) \cdot v'(z) \\ &= \frac{2x}{t} v'(z)\\ u_{xx} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{2x}{t} \right) \cdot v'(z) + \frac{2x}{t} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} v'(z) \\ &= \frac{2}{t} v'(z) + \frac{4x^{2}}{t^{2}}v''(z) \end{align} Now substitute into the PDE and simplify.